# Not even root can `ls .Trashes` on external disk in MacOS

Tags: command-line, sudo, root, macos

I want to look in the trash directory on an external disk connected to my Mac.

```
db@15 ~ % cd /Volumes/2TB/.Trashes 
db@15 .Trashes % ls
ls: .: Operation not permitted
db@15 .Trashes % sudo su
Password:
shell-init: error retrieving current directory: getcwd: cannot access parent directories: No such file or directory
sh-3.2# ls
job-working-directory: error retrieving current directory: getcwd: cannot access parent directories: No such file or directory
ls: .: Operation not permitted
sh-3.2# cd ..
chdir: error retrieving current directory: getcwd: cannot access parent directories: No such file or directory
sh-3.2# pwd
/Volumes/2TB
sh-3.2# ls -lO
d-wx--x--t@   5 su        staff     hidden         170 Aug  6 21:30 .Trashes
sh-3.2# xattr .Trashes
com.apple.FinderInfo
sh-3.2# chmod o+r .Trashes
chmod: Unable to change file mode on .Trashes: Operation not permitted
```

What now? There seem to be no *flags* that applies and just one *extended attribute*.

**Why can't root ls or chmod this directory?**

Comment: Have you added Terminal to System Preferences > Security & Privacy > Privacy > Full Disk Access?

Comment: Can you show the output of ˋmount | grep  2TBˋ?

Answer (score 1):

On my imac, I went to /Volumes/MyBook/.Trashes and I just tried `sudo ls` and it worked. It asked me for a password and then listed the contents. I was able to do `sudo ls` from then on without the password.

Comment: Yes that is the way sudo is designed to worth. Sudo SU is usually the wrong thing to do. You do not want to be in the root shell

Comment: `sudo ls` didn't work either.

Comment: were you in the Trashes directory when you ran sudo ls?